# Compare two files with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to compare two files and print the output if they match on some fields.

File1.txt:

```
bart:29482164591748
 apu:29482164591748
smithers:68468468468464
lisa:68468468468464
maggie:2348578903247548
```

File2.txt:

```
68468468468464:keyboard
68463894578424:user
29482164591748:computer
```

I would like this output:

```
bart:29482164591748:computer
```

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`?

Comment: You may be more successful with `join`, IIRC.

Comment: Hi, nope, anything that will get the job done. Cheers

Comment: Also: If you join on numeric key, you the `smithers` record also matches.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Both lisa's and smither's codes are present in File1, why should only bart be printed?

Comment: @terdon, I need each line to be printed not just one, sorry i would have been more specific.

Comment: What is the *exact* output (post it with all example lines please) you want from this 2 files?

Comment: @ChrisJ don't apologize, _fix it_ :). [Edit] your question as requested and show us something that is actually representative of your data. Comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. All relevant information must be in the question itself. You mentioned you can have duplicate lines. You need to show that in your example.

Answer (score 6):

A classic with `join`:

```
join -t: -1 2 -2 1 -o 2.1,1.1,1.2 <(sort -t: -k1,1 file1) <(sort -t: -k2,2 file2)
```

- `-t:` specifies the colon as separator.
- `-1 2` file1's join field is the second one
- `-2 1` file2's join field is the first one
- `-o 2.1,1.1,1.2` the output format.
- `<(...)`: both files must be sorted on the join field (`-k1,1` and `-k2,2`), `-t:` specifies the colon as separator for `sort`.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$2]{print $1":"$2":"a[$2]}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
bart:29482164591748:computer
smithers:68468468468464:keyboard
lisa:68468468468464:keyboard
```

Explanation:

- `awk -F:` start awk treating colon as a fields delimiter
- `NR==FNR{}` process only the first file
- `a[$1]=$2;next` build an array `a` indexed by the first field with values of the second field then skip to the next row
- `a[$2]{}` process only if value of previously build array with the index of the current second field is not empty (this is done only for the file2, because of the `next` word in the previous expression)
- `print $1":"$2":"a[$2]` print everything as desired

---

**After question edit:**

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$2]{print $1":"$2":"a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
bart:29482164591748:computer
 apu:29482164591748:computer
smithers:68468468468464:keyboard
lisa:68468468468464:keyboard
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tested and it seems to work however what i stupidly failed to mention is that there will be duplicate lines, any ideas please

Comment: @ChrisJ There are a lot of ideas, but you need to show sample input and expected output with duplicate lines.

Comment: Hi, I will update the description. I don't suppose you know if there is a 400 line limit on awk is there and thats' where it seems to stop?

Comment: @ChrisJ Definitely there is no 400 lines limit in awk.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to flip it round please, Ill update the description

Comment: @ChrisJ I updated the answer, but still don't get the output what you wrote in question. Please re-think precisely what you want.

Comment: @ChrisJ we can't guess what you need. When asking a question, you need to show us precisely what you expect. People have answered you and then you keep changing the requirements around. Take a few minutes, think about what you need and give us an exact example please.

Comment: @jimmij I realise this is an old post, but this is of interest to me. However, while I think I understand most of it, I can't quite fathom how it delivers the outcome (and a new question would be a duplicate). I have tried the before edit and after edit versions and both worked as they should. If you have time could you eleborate on how it works?

Comment: @BumblingBadger See the edit.

Comment: @jimmij Appreciated! Can you tell me how does your second answer (for the edited question) solve the duplicate field issue? If I'm not mistaken (and I understood the question), it looks as though the output should have been 'bart' and 'smithers' rather than 'lisa' and 'bart' as the first reference of the number (68468468468464) is adjacent to 'smithers'. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BumblingBadger The question was modified multiple times and honestly I do not understand what OP wanted to do. Other answers in this topic don't help solving this mystery either. Looking at it right now I think that the most sense is to match bart-computer, apu-computer, smithers-keyboard and lisa-keyboard, so I changed my second answer once again accordingly. So I just switched input files and left "duplicates'. If you have similar problem and just want to select first record add `,a[$2]=""` before last `}`.

Comment: @jimmij I see what you are saying. Agreed, looking at the comments, the OP was not clear on what they wanted. That said, I apreciate the ```,a[$2]=""```. Personally, it's not for production, just practise, but handy nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't use `awk`, but would use `perl` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#open both files for reading
open( my $input1, '<', "file1.txt" ) or die $!;
open( my $input2, '<', "file2.txt" ) or die $!;

#read the key-values into a hash called lookup. 
my %lookup = do { local $/; <$input1> =~ m/(\d+):(\w+)/g; };

#iterate by line of second file
while ( <$input2> ) { 
    #trim trailing linefeeds
    chomp;
    #split current line on :
    my ( $user, $key ) = split /:/;
    #if exists in original lookup, display record 
    if ( $lookup{$key} ) {
        print join ( ":", $user, $key, $lookup{$key}),"\n";
    }
}
```

I get a slightly different output though - specifically:

```
bart:29482164591748:computer
smithers:68468468468464:keyboard
lisa:68468468468464:keyboard
```

I'm not sure why the second 2 *shouldn't* be printed based on matching key-values.

If you want a one liner that's basically the same:

```
perl -F: -lane "print $k{$F[0]}.':'.$_ if $k{$F[0]}; $k{$F[1]}//=$F[0];" file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: I think it's a little bit overkill for this usecase

Comment: Why? It's doing basically the same thing as that `awk` fragment, although I'll grant it's more verbose. Didn't think we were playing code golf here.

Comment: I just place the question in the context of bash script, use perl oneliner could be usefull, but add a significent peace of other language code should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I don't see that in the OP's question. I do see "Hi, nope, anything that will get the job done."